# Hugo reference frontmatter image: in index.html

Tags: markdown, hugo, yaml-front-matter, hugo-content-organization

I have fontmatter that looks like

```
---
title: "My First Post"
date: 2023-04-07T22:11:00+02:00
draft: false
slug: "hi-first-post"
tags: ['tg1','tag2']
image: "images/featured.jpg"
---
```

in my index.html I have

```
{{ range .Site.RegularPages.ByDate.Reverse }}
{{ if and (eq .Section "story") (not .Draft) (le .Date $.Date) }}
{{$image := resources.Get "images/dogs.webp" }}
            <img src="{{ ($image).RelPermalink }}" alt="Image for {{ .Title }}"></a>
{{end}}{{end}}
```

However, I want to reference the image: from frontmatter.
The images are all stored in assets/images

I am trying to do it this way because i am trying to migrate a project to hugo. if i have to make folder for each post inside of content it will be a huge pain.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by using

```
 {{ $image := resources.GetMatch (printf "**%s" .Params.images) }}
     {{ with $image }}
     <img src="{{ ($image).RelPermalink }}" alt="Image for {{ .Title }}"></a>
     {{ end }}
```